# The relationship between thread and process in multi-process program

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

OS: debian9.
A simple multi-processes program named `mprocesses.py`.

```
import os
import multiprocessing

def run_task(name):
    print("task %s (pid = %s) is running"  %(name,os.getpid()))
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("current process %s ." %os.getpid())
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 2)
    for i in range(2):
        pool.apply_async(run_task,args=(i,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Run `python3 mprocesses.py` and get below output.

```
python3 mprocesses.py
current process 6145 .
task 0 (pid = 6146) is running
task 1 (pid = 6147) is running
```

Get processes info.

```
ps lax |grep 'python3 mprocesses.py' |grep -v grep 
0  1000  6145  5615  20   0 275428 14600 -      Sl+  pts/1      0:00 python3 mprocesses.py
1  1000  6146  6145  20   0  54232 10340 -      R+   pts/1      1:01 python3 mprocesses.py
1  1000  6147  6145  20   0  54232 10348 -      R+   pts/1      1:01 python3 mprocesses.py
```

Check processes tree view.

```
pstree -p 5615
bash(5615)───python3(6145)─┬─python3(6146)
                           ├─python3(6147)
                           ├─{python3}(6148)
                           ├─{python3}(6149)
                           └─{python3}(6150)
```

What confused me is the three threads 6148,6149,6150.
Does that mean every process contain one process ? 
Maybe my logical graph is better to express relationships between processes and threads here.

```
bash(5615)───python3(6145)─┬─────────────────python3(6146)
                           |                    └─{python3}(6149)
                           |             
                           ├──────────────────python3(6147)
                           ├─{python3}(6148)     └─{python3}(6150)
```

1.bash(5615) is the `python3 mprocesses.py`(6145) 's father process.
2.`python3 mprocesses.py`(6145)  contains two processes 6146 and 6147 created by `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 2)`.
3.Process(6145) contain thread(6148),Process(6146) contain thread(6149),Process(6147) contain thread(6150).
It does no matter which exact process id contain which thread id.
Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have:

- 3 processes (1 parent process and 2 children to match your `processes = 2` argument)
- 2 threads in each process (1 main thread, and 1 communication and management thread)

The extra communication and management thread per process is an implementation detail of the `multiprocessing` module; if you are sharing resources between processes more threads may be used. You can see hints that threads are used for these tasks in the documentation

For example, under [*Pipes and Queues*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues):

> **Note**: When an object is put on a queue, the object is pickled *and a background thread* later flushes the pickled data to an underlying pipe.
>
> [...]
>
> `class multiprocessing.Queue([maxsize])`
>    Returns a process shared queue implemented using a pipe and a few locks/semaphores. When a process first puts an item on the queue *a feeder thread is started* which transfers objects from a buffer into the pipe.

(italic emphasis mine)

You don't need to worry about these threads; they are there to implement the multiprocessing functionality and make it all run smoothly.